# RHEL6: Zabbix server/web mysql package not available

Tags: rhel, zabbix

Trying to install `zabbix-server-mysql` and `zabbix-web-mysql` through:

```
yum install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql
```

After installing the repository by:

```
rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.0/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

But keep getting following error:

```
No package zabbix-server-mysql available.
No package zabbix-web-mysql available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Same issue even when trying to install the package from its repo directory, such:

```
yum install http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.0/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Any advise?

Comment: After installing the repo, what's the output of `yum repolist all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the repo directories.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/